# Timer doesnt go lower?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-clock

I'm creating a Snake game. When I lower the cooldown of the Timer I want the snake to move faster.

It's actually working, but only if I change the number of the game speed before starting the project. If I start the project and change the timer in game, by a function, then var for the timer gets lower (printed it in different situations) but the speed doesn't change.

```
game_speed = 100
SCRREEN_UPDATE = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(SCRREEN_UPDATE, game_speed)

while go:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    if not game_over:
        screen.fill((0,90,10))
        snake.draw_grass()
        for event in events:
            main_game.Quit(event)
            if event.type == SCRREEN_UPDATE:
                 main_game.update()

self.list.append(self.user_input)
self.user_input = int(self.user_input)
if isinstance(self.user_input,str):
   self.list = [0]
   self.user_input = "0"
game_speed -= int(self.list[-1]) 
self.list = [0]
self.user_input = "0"
print(game_speed)
return game_speed
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much.... could you explain why i had to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The timer event and the `game_speed` variable are not tied. The timer interval doesn't magically change when you change the value of `game_speed`. You have to restart the timer with the new interval. So after changing `game_speed`, `pygame.time.set_timer` needs to be called again:

```py
game_speed -= int(self.list[-1]) 
pygame.time.set_timer(SCRREEN_UPDATE, game_speed)
```